# Hint text color for SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

How to set Hint text color in SearchView?

```
<SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:transitionGroup="true" />
```

I tried :

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/grey</item>
```

And :

```
<string name="search_hint">Search for a contact<font fgcolor="#ffbbbbbb"></font></string>
```

But none of them applied hint text color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the hint text color by setting a theme to your `SearchView`.

```
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"
        android:transitionGroup="true" />
```

And in your `styles.xml` create the style.

```
    <style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/grey</item>
    </style>
```